# Move/Rotate/Scale without needing to hit the gizmo with your mouse

Tags: interface, transforms

I have turned on the Maya settings (I'm coming from Maya, and in the beginning I want to keep the learning curve as small as possible).

Is there (in these settings) something similar like in Maya the Shift+MiddleMouseButton?

Shift+MMB would let you apply the transformations (over one axis) without explicitly selecting the small gizmo. You could just hold your mouse anywhere above the viewport, move globally in the direction of the X, Y or Z axis and it would just transform in that direction.

For me it's a really intuitive way of modeling, because I don't have to select a small gizmo for every transformation.

Is there something similar in these settings?

Comment: Try G (for Grab) then X (or Y or Z) for Global, X again for Local transform and click mouse to apply. You can also use S for Scale or R for Rotation. Though I don't know if it will work the same with Maya settings. I would recommend learning the Blender shortcuts - one hand on the mouse, the other on the keyboard is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

As @Aardenon said, you can push <kbd>G</kbd> to use the grab tool. From there, pushing <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> will lock it to that axis. If you're in edit mode, pushing <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> again will allow you to move your selection on a local axis, and in object mode, this just unlocks the axis.

Also, you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + [axis] to exclude that axis from the lock (e.g. holding <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> will lock the transform to the Y and Z axes).

This also works with the rotate tool (<kbd>R</kbd>key ) and the scale tool ( <kbd>S</kbd> key).

Answer (score 1):

I know how to use it with 3ds Max interaction:
move - SHIFT+W
rotate - SHIFT+E
scale - SHIFT+R
then press X,Y or Z for constraint or SHIFT+axis to exclude that axis